# How can I apply a factorial formula which works with rational numbers, not only integers?

Tags: javascript, php, formula

I'm wondering how to apply a factorial formula which works with rational numbers, not only integers on PHP or JavaScript, and even what's the formula.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you will need to use the Gamma function. The relation of factorial to gamma function is:
n! = gamma(n + 1)

As to how to calculate the Gamma function, you will need to use an algorithm to approximate this as it requires integration if you were to do it purely mathematically.

The most widely used algorithm is the Lanczos approximation method. You can refer to pseudo-code for this over here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation

Hope that helps!